# Manually scaling/adjusting PNG exports in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, png, shiny

I have a quick question. I have written an app that I run on shinyapps.io. Part of the page generates a graph, through ggplot2, that I offer users the ability to download.

When exporting the file, the image is stretched right to the borders of the overall png size. My titles, x/y axis titles and the legend are all right against the edge of the frame.

Is there any quick way to either center the image by scaling it inwards from the frame of the page, or add padding and/or margins to the entire graph image?

Here is my export code:

```
output$downloadPlot <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() { paste(input$get.id," _Chart", '.png', sep='') },
      content = function(file) {
        device <- function(..., width, height) grDevices::png(..., width = width, height = height, res = 300, units = "in")
        ggsave(file, plot = p(), device = device,scale=1.95)
      }
    )
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Setting aside the Shiny steps, are you asking whether a plot can have a border around the panel?  Then, the ggsave with .png would preserve the effect of the panel being "centered", no?

Comment: @lawyeR No a literal border, although perhaps that will help with the solution. When I go to print out the graph, sometimes the labels are cut-off because they were so close to the edge of the frame of the PNG. I want to create some padding around all the features of the graph so that, say on an 8.5 x 11 piece of paper, there is a 1/4" gap between the labels and the edge of the paper.

Comment: Why don't you expand the x-axis, using scale?  That way, you will have some extra space for labels.  scale_x_continuous(limits = etc.)

Comment: @lawyeR I'll look into it, thank you for the feedback. My initial skepticism with that is that I'm more worried about the title and legend as well. I don't think shifting the axis will improve that aspects.

Comment: With the title you can always use newline \n; with legends, you can make multiple rows.

Comment: *UPDATE* I ended up scrapping one of the legend items, and then lowering res and scale of the PNG graph. I made sure to manually override width and height in the device function to be 0.5" smaller than the page size.